# Disable a button based on CONDITION in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

How can i add disabled class with attributes to field based on CONDITION?

I tried as below methods,

1)

```
<t t-if="product.qty_available &lt;= 0">
    <attribute name="class">btn btn-primary btn-lg mt8 js_check_product a-submit disabled</attribute>
</t>
```

---

2)

```
<attribute name="class" t-if="product.qty_available &gt; 0">btn btn-primary btn-lg mt8 js_check_product a-submit disabled</attribute>
```

---

3)

```
<attribute name="class" >product.qty_available &gt; 0 and 'btn btn-primary btn-lg mt8 js_check_product a-submit' or 'btn btn-primary btn-lg mt8 js_check_product a-submit disabled'</attribute>
```

---

Can some one helping me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did with position="replace"

```
<xpath expr="//a[@id='add_to_cart']" position="replace">
      <a id="add_to_cart" t-attf-class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt8 js_check_product a-submit #{product.qty_available &lt;= 0 and 'disabled'}" href="#" >Add to Cart</a>
  </xpath>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this one:

```
<attribute name="t-att-disabled" > "1 if product.qty_available else 0" </attribute>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: When i try with first one, irrespective of condition button got disabled. because in HTML page for any filed if it finds the disabled attribute, immediately it will disable, so, disabled=true or disable=false, not a matter it will disable.

Comment: when i try with second one, button not disabled at all both for qty >0 and qty <=0

Comment: I forgot to mention that , i am trying to implement this within a Template

Comment: use the else '0' or else 'False'  in the  first one,

Comment: no luck, same result. Button got disabled in both the conditions  qty >0 and qty <=0

Comment: after page gets loaded also, in html page getting field attribute like, disabled=" '1' if product.qty_available > 0 else '0' " its not getting replaced with '1' or '0'

Comment: i have update my answer  <attribute name="t-att-disabled" > "1 if product.qty_available else 0" </attribute>

Comment: Same like before. irrespective of condition button got disabled. HTML doesn't use boolean values for boolean attributes, surprisingly, some one explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745276/explicitly-set-disabled-false-in-the-html-does-not-work

Comment: Thanks for spending time to answer the questions in Stackoverflow. For my previous questions instead of answers i got -ve reputation. Final attempt to me to try with position="replace", i will try with it and if succeeds i will post my answer.