# The proper use of t-attf-class to disable a button in header buttons with Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, qweb

I've been trying to use `t-attf-class` in order to disable a button in the `header` section of Odoo (v11).
I've created a button in the header in the view xml file and link it with an action in the model, the action works fine.
I'm try to disable the button based on the `state` condition of the object, I found in the source of Odoo the following template:

```
<t t-name="FieldStatus.content.button">
    <t t-set="disabled" t-value="!clickable || i.selected"/>
    <button type="button" t-att-data-value="i.id" t-att-disabled="disabled ? 'disabled' : undefined"
        t-attf-class="btn btn-sm o_arrow_button btn-#{i.selected ? 'primary' : 'default'}#{disabled ? ' disabled' : ''}">
        <t t-esc="i.display_name"/>
    </button>
</t>
```

So I'm trying to do the same for this button:

```
<form string="Form Name">
<header>
...
<button name="action_delete" string="Delete" type="object" t-attf-class="btn-danger #{state == 'done'?' disabled': ''}" t-att-disabled="state == 'done' ? 'disabled': undefined"/>
...
</header>
```

the model contains a field `state` which takes one of the values: `['draft', 'pending', 'done']`
This action `action_delete` is defined in the model and it works fine.
I've tried to use the `<attribute>`inside the button, and the `t-if` attribute inside and outside of the button with no luck.

P.S. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477673/disable-a-button-based-on-condition-in-odoo/37481827#37481827) is different and the answer doesn't work for this case, also this can be achieved using the `invisible` attribute which is much easier but we do not want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just using the default Odoo way, by making it invisible on some states?

```xml
<button name="action_delete" string="Delete" type="object"
    attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['state1', 'state2'])]}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I knew this way actually, the invisible option is not the best way in my case, the user is not expecting this behavior and may consider the feature unimplemented.

Comment: Yeah okay makes sense.