# Any way to conditionally disable a Spring form:select?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl

If I'm using a standard HTML `<select>` tag, I can optionally disable it based on a given condition, by placing something like the following within the tag:

```
${myCondition ? 'disabled' : ''}
```

However, when using Spring's Form Tag Library, I can't place an expression within the tag. Is there any way, when using the Spring `form:select` tag, to disable the `select` conditionally, without resorting to JavaScript?

Comment: Did you try like this: <form:select disabled="${condition.disabled}"> ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, setting disabled="false" doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745276/explicitly-set-disabled-false-in-the-html-does-not-work

Comment: @awagenhoffer You're quite right though: The Spring tag translates disabled="true/false" correctly. Thanks for the correct response.

Comment: You are welcome