# how to disable next button when the input is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm tring to create a multiple login form , every was fine but i want to disable next button if the email input is empty.
the input class="email"
and the button class ="btn-next"
i will appreciate any help thanks.

```
<sub>const pageBox = document.querySelector('.page-box');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.btn-next');
const btnBack = document.querySelector('.btn-back');
const checkboxPass = document.querySelector('.checkbox-pass');
const passwordInput = document.querySelector('.password');
const loginTitle = document.querySelector('.loginTitle-text');
const userEmail = document.querySelector('.user-email');
const emailInput = document.querySelector('.email');

btnNext.onclick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    pageBox.classList.add('active-pass');
    setTimeout(() => passwordInput.focus(), 500);
    loginTitle.innerHTML = 'Welcome';
    userEmail.innerHTML = ''  + emailInput.value;
};

btnBack.onclick = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    pageBox.classList.remove('active-pass');
    loginTitle.innerHTML = 'Sign in';
    userEmail.innerHTML = 'Please continue,';
    emailInput.focus();
};

checkboxPass.onclick = () => {
    if(checkboxPass.checked) {
        passwordInput.type = 'text';
    }
    else{
       passwordInput.type = 'password';
    }
};
emailInput.addEventListener("btnNext", (e) => {
    preventDefault();
    btnNext.disabled()
    if(emailInput.value.length  > 0) {
        btnNext.disabled = 'true';
     }
     else{
        btnNext.disabled = 'false';
    } 
});
</sub>
```

Comment: Your code seems invalid. What is `emailInput.addEventListener("btnNext"...` - there is no such event `btnNext`.Moreover change `preventDefault();` to `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: ok, thank you so much,

Comment: you can please enlighten more cos that is the part i'm not getting right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's no `btnNext` event, use `input` (when the input is changed)
2. Add or remove a `disabled` attribute for the button based on the input's value.

Setting `disabled="false"` doesn't work as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745276/explicitly-set-disabled-false-in-the-html-does-not-work).

```js
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.btn-next');
const emailInput = document.querySelector('.email');

emailInput.addEventListener("input", () => emailInput.value.length ? btnNext.removeAttribute('disabled') : btnNext.setAttribute('disabled', ''));
```

```html
<input type="email" class="email"/>
<button class="btn-next" disabled>Next</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked.   is it proper to say length == any number i prefer in place of the question mark?

Comment: @jorgejo26 yes, you can do `emailInput.value.length > 4` to enable the button if the email is more than 4 length. BUT if you use `<input type="email">` you can use `emailInput.validity.valid' so the input validate a proper email. More precise email matching could be done with `pattern` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your current code,

```js
emailInput.addEventListener("btnNext", (e) => {
    preventDefault();
    btnNext.disabled()
    if(emailInput.value.length  > 0) {
        btnNext.disabled = 'true';
     }
     else{
        btnNext.disabled = 'false';
    } 
});
```

try to change to this code,

```js
emailInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(emailInput.value.length  > 0) {
        btnNext.disabled = 'true';
     }
     else{
        btnNext.disabled = 'false';
    } 
});
```

Comment: okay, thank you again and again, i so much appreciate.

Comment: @jorgejo26 Please mark it as an answer if this solution resolved your issue

Comment: okay, but it's not working yet, i don't know why.   i think there is need to add btnnext=disable before the if statement

Comment: @jorgejo26 Does the code I provided work only with adding `btnNext.disabled()`?

Comment: i have tried it but not working yet.        emailInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    btnNext.disabled()

    if(emailInput.value.length  > 0) {
        btnNext.disabled = 'true';
     }
     else{
        btnNext.disabled = 'false';
    } 
});